# Case statement to flag Date format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a column called "start_date" as below. The datatype of start_date is "text".

```
start_date

2019-02-28
2020-01-30
31-02-2019
```

If the date format is "yyyy-mm-dd" then i want to flag it as '0'. Else we need to flag it as 1. how can we implement this using case statement.

Expected output

```
start_date  Flag

2019-02-28   0
2020-01-30   0
31-02-2019   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This may be close enough for your purposes:

```
select (not (start_date ~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$')) as flag
```

This checks that the format is DDDD-DD-DD.  It does not validate that the date is actually valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more detailed expression try:

```
'^((0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$)|^(\d\d(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])-02-29$)'
```

It may be better to hide this behind a function. The following function evaluates whether a string contains a an ISO formatted date. It returns true if so otherwise false, unless the parameter is null, in which it returns null. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a7e53c52a4f892da688b4b0de694f5b).

```
create or replace 
function is_valid_iso_date (iso_date_string text)
    returns boolean
   language sql 
   immutable strict
/*
  regexp to determine if a string is validly formatted as an ISO_DATE. Format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
  
  The following validates a string as being a valid ISO date  (or not) for dates range
  between 0001-01-01 and 9999-12-31 including leap days (Feb-29). 
  It is however based on a faulty assumption: That the Georgian Calendar has been official and 
  consistent 0001-01-01 but this is not true. The Georgian Calendar was introduced in OCT 1582. 
 */   
as $$
    select iso_date_string ~ '^((0[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))$)|^(\d\d(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])-02-29$)'
$$;
```